# why ORA-01403: No Data Found error is showing

Tags: c#, oracle

I am  developing a ASP.NET web app using Oracle 11g at backend. I have written a separate SP for fetching User Login Data and flags from database table. Please find below code snippet in FetchUserLoginData() Method:

```
String spName = "FETCH_USER_LOGIN_ROLE_DATA";

            OracleCommand dbCheckLogin=new OracleCommand();
            OracleDataReader LoginDataReader=null;

            dbCheckLogin = dbCon.GetDBCommand(spName,dbCheckLogin);

            dbCheckLogin.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("USERID", LoginID));
            dbCheckLogin.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("USERPWD", Password));

            dbCheckLogin.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("USERGUI_ID", OracleType.VarChar,2000)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            dbCheckLogin.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ADMIN_FLG", OracleType.VarChar,20)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            dbCheckLogin.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("CLOSED_FLG", OracleType.VarChar,20)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            dbCheckLogin.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("LOCKED_FLG", OracleType.VarChar,20)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            dbCheckLogin.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("LOGGEDIN_FLG", OracleType.VarChar,20)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            dbCheckLogin.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("USER_FLG", OracleType.VarChar,20)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            dbCheckLogin.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("SEASED_FLG", OracleType.VarChar,20)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            LoginDataReader = dbCheckLogin.ExecuteReader();


            while (LoginDataReader.Read())
            {

                user.USER_SL = Convert.ToString(LoginDataReader["USER_SL"]);
                user.ISADMIN=LoginDataReader["ISADMIN"].ToString();
                user.ISCLOSED = LoginDataReader["ISCLOSED"].ToString();
                user.ISLOCKED = LoginDataReader["ISLOCKED"].ToString();
                user.ISLOGGEDIN = LoginDataReader["ISLOGGEDIN"].ToString();
                user.ISPOWERUSER = LoginDataReader["ISPOWERUSER"].ToString();
                user.ISSEASED= LoginDataReader["ISSEASED"].ToString();
            }
```

Now problem is, when I tried to run without any SP, just writing and executing a direct query, there is no problem, it fetches data from database perfectly well. In case of SP, i got an exception: No DATA Found. I am giving a correct userName and password eachtime, still it can not fetch any data. Even I tried to run the procedure from SQLDeveloper or PL/SQL and found no problem. The problem only lies when I tried to execute SP from server side coding.

Comment: Is there a reason you were passing `LoginID` twice? You used the same value for both username and password??

Comment: @codingbiz: that was a typo mistake. I corrected it in code, still dont work. DataReader cant fetch any data from table.

Comment: Try to add an output command in `FETCH_USER_LOGIN_ROLE_DATA` sqlcommand,then figure out what it is the problem in current sql.

Comment: There must be issue in SP. Are you using any 'select column_value in @varible from Tablename' type query in SP. this query would not be returning any record, thats why you would be getting above exception. Also check types and size datatypes of parameter declared in your SP.

Comment: can you post your SP Codes?

Comment: Thanks all for your help. I have finally figured it out. I just forgot to return the reference cursor and without it DataReader and Datatables wont get any data from SP. It happens in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that worked for me is to add reference cursor to be returned from SP. There was a problem with SP and now I figured it out. Without returning cursor, DataTable, DataSet, DataReader, DataAdapters dont get any data fetched from SP even it is supposed to do so. I am giving my full SP here, if it comes to any help to others.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FETCH_USER_LOGIN_ROLE_DATA
(
 USERID IN VARCHAR2  
,USERPWD IN VARCHAR2
,OUT_CURSR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) 
AS 
BEGIN
OPEN OUT_CURSR FOR
   SELECT 
      U.ROWID,U.USER_SL,U.ISADMIN,U.ISPOWERUSER,
      U.ISLOCKED,U.ISCLOSED,U.ISSEASED,U.ISLOGGEDIN
   FROM USERS U
   WHERE U.USER_ID=USERID AND
         U.USER_PWD=USERPWD;
END FETCH_USER_LOGIN_ROLE_DATA;
```